# Command to cycle commands?

Tags: command-line, keyboard-shortcuts, command

Is there a command containing `command1`, `command2`, `command3`, `command4`, `etc` that when run will **cycle** between these?

My idea would be then to use that one command with a **shortcut or launcher** (in `~/.local/share/applications` for example, or a panel or dock launcher) to cycle between different commands .

I am looking for something similar to what [`disper`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/disper.1.html) does to cycle displays: `disper --cycle-stages='-e : -c : -S : -s' --cycle` is a command that cycles between commands that can be run separately: `disper -e`, `disper -c`, `disper -S`, `disper-s`. It helps cycling between what otherwise would be different commands.

But while `disper` is for cycling displays, I want to know if there is a CLI tool that would **cycle between any separate commands**. I am thinking about cycling displays without using `disper`, which doesn't always work; for example, I would in this way have a launcher or shortcut to cycle commands like:

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --auto --output LVDS1 --off 
xrandr --output VGA1 --auto --left-of LVDS1 --output LVDS1 --auto --primary 
xrandr --output VGA1 --auto --left-of LVDS1 --primary --output LVDS1 --auto  
xrandr --output VGA1 --off --output LVDS1 --auto
```

It should be something like: `cycling-tool 'command1, command2, command3, command4'`

---

*I am a medium GUI user and not at all advanced in using CLI. If there are reasons of principle for which what I ask is not possible, please provide an answer in terms suitable to a certain level of vulgarization (not too esoteric).*

Comment: For a generic solution, the command would have to save state somewhere.

Comment: Not being familiar with disper, do you want this cycling-tool to call each of the 4 commands in sequence?

Comment: @JeffSchaller - the Main-command should each time trigger the *next* Command-in-the-series. (But this is a question that I ask out of curiosity more than anything else, and the real answer to "Is there etc?"  might very well be "NO".)

Answer (score 1):

If you are in BASH shell,

```
Ctrl + r   Recall the last command including the specified character(s)
             searches the command history as you type.
```

You can try `Ctrl + r` and type first common characters between all the commands like `disp`. If you keep `ctrl` pressed and repeat `r`, shell will cycle through the commands.

Comment: Maybe my question isn't clear. I want a single command that could be triggered by shortcut or launcher (panel, dock, desktop launcher, etc) in a desktop interface (not in console) in order to cycle between different commands

Comment: I can't recollect having seen anything like that. I suppose it can be achieved with a tiny script leveraging `xargs`